# spark.createDataFrame creates a DF but df.collect.foreach(println) fails with RuntimeException

Tags: scala, apache-spark, dataframe, rdd

Spark version: `Scala 2.12.8 (Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM, Java 1.8.0_211)`

In the following code, `spark.createDataFrame` creates a DF but the dataframe is useless (I can't print it or do anything with it).

```scala
val fieldSeparator = '\u001D' // 1D = group separator; 21 = !; 7C = |;
val recordSeparator = '\u001E' // 1E = record separator

val myRDD = dataSet.toDF().rdd.take(10)
    .map(r => r.mkString(fieldSeparator.toString))
val schema = new StructType()
    .add("displayname", StringType, true)
    .add("reputation", IntegerType, true)
    .add("numberOfPosts", LongType, true)
    .add("score", DoubleType, true)

println("---------- Creating DF from RDD: --------------")
val df = spark.createDataFrame(
    spark.sparkContext
         .parallelize(myRDD.map(r => r.split(fieldSeparator.toString)))
         .map(a => Row.fromSeq(a)),
    schema
)
println("---------- Successfully created DF from RDD (?) --------------")

println(df.getClass) // this prints: class org.apache.spark.sql.Dataset
df.printSchema()
/*
   root
   |-- displayname: string (nullable = true)
   |-- reputation: integer (nullable = true)
   |-- numberOfPosts: long (nullable = true)
   |-- score: double (nullable = true)
*/
myRDD.foreach(println) // prints all records correctly
df.collect.foreach(println)
// this fails with error: RuntimeException: java.lang.String is not a valid
// external type for schema of int ???
```

The result should be same as `myRDD.foreach(println)` which works fine.

Comment: Have you found the answer you were looking for?

Answer (score 1):

Let's first create a minimal, reproducible instance of your problem. BTW, this is what you should try to do each time you ask a question ;-)

```scala
// A RDD of string
val rdd = sc.parallelize(Seq("oli,15,56,0.5", "you,45,49987787,0.4"))

// your schema
val schema = new StructType() 
    .add("displayname", StringType, true)
    .add("reputation", IntegerType, true)
    .add("numberOfPosts", LongType, true)
    .add("score", DoubleType, true)

// Now, let's try to create a dataframe
val rddOfRows = rdd.map(_.split(",")).map(Row.fromSeq(_))
val df = spark.createDataFrame(rddOfRows, schema)
// we can print its schema
df.printSchema
root
 |-- displayname: string (nullable = true)
 |-- reputation: integer (nullable = true)
 |-- numberOfPosts: long (nullable = true)
 |-- score: double (nullable = true)

// but show triggers the exception you mentioned
df.show
  java.lang.RuntimeException: java.lang.String is not a valid external type for
  schema of int
```

Why? You need to remember that spark is lazy. As long as you do not collect or write data, spark does nothing. When you use `createDataFrame`, nothing happens. This is why you do not get any errors. When you print the schema, spark simply prints the schema you provided. Yet, when I call `show`, I ask spark to do something and it triggers all the dependent computations.

The problem you see is that spark is expecting an int, but you provide a string. Spark does not cast your data when creating the dataframe. You have several possibilities to solve your problem. One solution could be to cast the fields beforehand like this:

```scala
val rddOfRow = rdd
  .map(_.split(","))
  .map(_ match { case Array(a, b, c, d) => (a, b.toInt, c.toLong, d.toDouble) })
  .map(Row.fromTuple(_))
// and the rest of the code remains unchanged
```